# extension failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1

I have Installed a Magento Extension, after that I have error failed to open stream: No such file or directory I don't know why?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, you only have to compile your Magento installation. Please let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: magento compilation is enabled in your source/website so magento loading all extension from `includes/src` folder. disable compilation then clear cache and re-enable compilation.

Comment: but when i want to go to the backend /admin i have this error front end it's work good it's there any way to disable comilation without backend ?

Answer (score 1):

you can disable it from source open `includes/config.php` file and add `#` before `define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');` code.

Comment: Add other steps mentioned in comment by you to make it a complete answer

Comment: VishwasBhatnagar Thanks, for correction. @Abdo Abo, please clear cache then re-enable compilation.